# communicate EJB project and java application with socket?

Tags: java, sockets, ejb

I need my EJB to communicate via sockets with a java application. Can this be done? Can I place the code for a client socket somewhere in the Bean (in a method?) and have the server code establish a connection and listen for requests from client on the java application?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read how to ask a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the EJB spec (e.g. EJB 3.2 core, chapter 16.2.2 "Programming Restrictions":

> An enterprise bean must not attempt to listen on a socket, accept connections on a socket, or use a socket for multicast.
>   The EJB architecture allows an enterprise bean instance to be a network socket client, but it does not allow it to be a network server. Allowing the instance to become a network server would conflict with the basic function of the enterprise bean— to serve the EJB clients.